# VC++: Insert text in textBox without repeat

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm with difficulties for insert a text in a textBox or RichtextBox without repeat.

This is code used:

```
    #include "windows.h"
    #pragma comment(lib, "user32")


    void actwnd()

    {

    wchar_t  lastwindow[MAX_PATH];
    wchar_t  currentwindow[MAX_PATH];
    HWND mainwindow;

    mainwindow = GetForegroundWindow();
    GetWindowText(mainwindow,currentwindow,sizeof(currentwindow));

    if(lastwindow==currentwindow)
            {
            }

            else
            if(lastwindow!=currentwindow)
            { 

            strcpy ((char*)lastwindow,(char*)currentwindow);
            String^ strNew = gcnew String(currentwindow);
        //  String^ wnd = gcnew String(reinterpret_cast(currentwindow));
            textBox1->Text += strNew;

            }
    }


    // Set interval for 1000ms in test
    private: System::Void timer1_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) 

        {

                     actwnd();
        }
```

Any help will appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if(lastwindow==currentwindow) does not compare the strings, it compares the addresses of the arrays, so they will never be equal. Use wcscmp to compare wchar_t arrays. Since these are wchar_t arrays, it is also invalid to be copying them with strcpy, which is only used with char arrays. Use wcscpy instead.

Comment: Thank @ScottMcP-MVP. Based in your clue, I achieved it make some changes of follow way => if(wcscmp(lastwindow,currentwindow)!=0)
  {        
   wcscpy (lastwindow,currentwindow);
  String^ strNew = gcnew String(currentwindow);
  textBox1->Text += strNew; } .Work fine now!